# How to get the right result sets instead of "system.data.datarow view" in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to input a column into a list from my local database. Somehow instead of showing the column value, all of the rows in the list show "system.data.datarow view".[image: Here is my code]

I found someone who had the similar problem to mine, but they solved by setting datavaluefield property. I tried to follow their instruction but I could not find the property they mentioned.

Comment: What is movieslist? What type of control is it?

Comment: Can you share what is the expected output and what is actual output? What is MoviesList?

Comment: Moiveslist is the name of list in the form. I wanna show the filmname as output showed in the movieslist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are passing the object name instead of the actual data.

Instead of `MoviesList.DataSource = filmNames.Tables["tblFilms"]`, You need to do something like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in filmNames.Tables["tblFilms"].Rows)
{
    MoviesList.Items.Add(row["Column_Name"].ToString());
}
```

Where `Column_Name` is the name of the column in your database which has the values you are trying to insert to the list.

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thank you so much. Just be curious, is it mandatory to use loop to fill data. Is there other ways to get the same result?

Comment: You can use `MoviesList.DataSourceID=` or `MoviesList.DataSource=`, by changing your list's `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. There are alot of examples online.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `MoviesList.DataSource = filmNames.Tables["tblFilms"]` please trythis one :

```
MoviesList = datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[0].ToString()).ToList();
```